# Can't inline plot inset_axes in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently trying to plot an inset axis into a matplotlib plot in a Jupyter Notebook, but I always get the following error:

```
TypeError: get_tightbbox() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bbox_extra_artists'
```

Minimal working example:

```
%matplotib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
import numpy as np

fig, axis = plt.subplots(1, 1)
axis.imshow(np.random.rand(5, 5))
ins_axes = inset_axes(axis, width=0.75, height=0.75, loc=1)
```

This is what the output looks like if I run the code as a script or without using `%matplotlib inline`:

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhkRK.png)

My matplotlib version is 3.0.1, jupyter is 1.0.0 and Python is 3.6.7.

I recently upgraded from matplotlib 1, where everything worked fine.

EDIT: matplotlib 3.0.0 caused another error to appear a lot earlier:

`AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'artist'`

EDIT2: Upgrading to matplotlib 3.0.2 did the trick, see [ImportanceOfBeingErnest's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53502546/2286972) answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12634) in matplotlib 3.0.1, which got fixed by [FIX: allow non bbox_extra_artists calls #12635](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12635).

You will need to update to matplotlib 3.0.2 or downgrade to 3.0.0.

Comment: This is indeed the bug I encountered! Upgrading to 3.0.2 fixed it, many thanks!

Comment: This works for me on VSCode and Jupyter notebook, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked fine.
Using matplotlib 3.0.0. Is this an issue of a newer/older version maybe?

Comment: 3.0.0 did not work for me (see edit above), I'll try a higher version next!